# Set whole background image/colour in WP7

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I can't seem work out (even though I have seen other apps) how to set the whole background of a WP7 page to a image or colour, like in Panorama for example.

If i set

```
  Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF0079C1"
```

Or

```
<Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/images/highwaysBack.jpg" Stretch="None" />
    </Grid.Background>
```

it still leaves the top info section either black or white depending on the phone setting.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's most likely the System Tray. You can hide that by setting shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False" on your page.

Answer (score 1):

Make a note that hiding the system tray isn't something you always want to do, as you're hiding info like the battery life. Only do it because you app absolutely has to, like a video game. If it's just a simpler app there shouldn't be a real neeed to hide it.

Comment: Very true. I usually enable it on the pages which involve downloading data, so the user can see if there is a signal or not.